# Do we cheat on $\int e^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

So this question seems weird at first look, I admit that.

$f(x)=e^x$ can we written as series as follows:
  $f(x)=e^x = \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+...$

Now differentiating $f(x)$ yields $e^x$ again, as we have an infinite number of summands and derivation of each summand gives the one to its left.

So far so good.

Now, basically everywhere we find this: $\int \mathrm{d}x \, e^x = e^x+C$ where C is the integration constant. Now this is, where I think we cheat a little. By integrating each summand of $f(x)$ we find, that each summand becomes the one to its right. But there's no one to the left of $1$. Do we in fact do this:

$\int \mathrm{d}x \, e^x = e^x -1 + C = e^x + \tilde{C}$ ? (with $\tilde{C}=C-1$)

Or is there another way to show, that indeed $\int \mathrm{d}x \, e^x=e^x+C$

Comment: If $C$ is a constant, then so too is $C-1$.  As far as finding an antiderivative goes, there is no difference.  So what is the question?

Comment: Exactly that is the question. I just wanted some approval of that.

Comment: In any circumstances, any equality between two antiderivatives must be understood as an equality up to addition of constant. So even $0 + C = 1 + C$ makes sense in this viewpoint. (Or more formally, you may regard the symbol $\int f(x) \, dx$ as the set of all antiderivatives of $f$, the constant of integration $C$ as the set of all constant functions, and interpret the formula as equality between sets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without caring about the constant:
$$De^x=e^x$$
So:
$$D^{-1}De^x=D^{-1}e^x$$
$$e^x=D^{-1}e^x$$
Where $D$ is the differential-operator.

Edit:
The antiderivate of $f$ is:
$$\int f=\{g\,|\,g'=f\}$$
And since both $a(x)=e^x$ and $b(x)=e^x-1$ has the property that $a'=b'=\exp$, so both of them are $\in\int\exp$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction since for [Foundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) C is an arbitrary constant thus

$$\int e^x\mathrm{d}x =(e^x-1)+C$$

and

$$\int e^x\mathrm{d}x =e^x$$

are equivalent.

Comment: I didn't mean that there's a contradiction. I just wanted clarification for myself, that this is actually the step, that is implied. Of course this question seems rather trivial, I admit.

Comment: @gimusi I'm a bit curious - Are you a math teacher?

Comment: @Botond No I'm a math learner, like all people here :)

Comment: @gimusi I wanted to ask if you are teaching math in your real life. By the way, I think I've seen you with fewer points than me :D

Comment: @Botond Of course, about 2 months ago! :)

Comment: @infinitezero alle question can lead to some interesting consideration!